# Combining arrays of diff sizes

Tags: python

I have this code that creates permutations of a given number. It also give the permuatations based on the number of specified digits, so 2 would give the permutations of all possible 2 digit values. I have this looped so for a 4 digit number, it would loop giving all permutations scenarios, like 4,3,2 and 1 digit permutations scenarios. The problem im having is how to store the perm variable which stores the permutations. I tried making a multi array perm, then as the loop iterates it adds the new array to the perm. Didn't work because the arrays are different sizes. How can I continue?

```
def fp(number):

    # A Python program to print all 
    # permutations using library function 
    from itertools import permutations 
  
    # Get all permutations of [1, 2, 3] 
    c= list(map(int,str(number)))
    print(c, len(c))
    i=1
    while i <= len(c):
        perm= permutations(c,i) #permuate the number c to the number of specified digits i
        i+=1

    
    # Print the obtained permutations 
    for i in list(perm): 
        print (i)
```

Comment: What is your end-goal here? How will you be using this function and the saved results? That should dictate how you store the results, as there are multiple options.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I tried making a multi array perm, then as the loop iterates it adds the new array to the perm. Didn't work because the arrays are different sizes." None of this makes any sense, for a variety of reasons. Please read [ask] and [mre] and *show the code* where you "tried" this, because the description is not understandable. If you are using Numpy, then **say so**; but there is no good reason to use Numpy for this. If you are just using Python's built-in `list`s, then please do not call them "arrays", and also there is no reason why such a problem would occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a powerset, search in these [functions by itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for powerset. I just changed the combinations to permutations.
Then loop through all permutations and append them to a list (you could also use a dictionary)

```
import itertools 
def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.permutations(s, r) for r in range(1,len(s)+1))

lst_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3]
out = []
for perm in powerset(lst_of_numbers):
    out.append(perm)

print(out)
```

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, this helped didn't know permutations exist. thank u

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable to hold all the permutations. Extend it with the list returned by each call to `permutations()`.

```
def fp(number):

    # A Python program to print all 
    # permutations using library function 
    from itertools import permutations 
  
    all_perms = []
    c= list(map(int,str(number)))
    print(c, len(c))
    i=1
    while i <= len(c):
        perm= permutations(c,i) #permuate the number c to the number of specified digits i
        all_perms.extend(perm)
        i+=1

    
    # Print the obtained permutations 
    for i in all_perms: 
        print (i)
```